# React onClick event calls API twice

Tags: reactjs, events

I have a simple React component, a button and a function which calls an API endpoint. When I click the button the API inside event gets called twice. I have read many posts here on stackoverflow and tried all of them but still have same issues. 
Moreover, even though I can see 2 records in db for each call, in the Google Dev tools shows only 1 xhr call which is wired.

I have already tried to pass function reference instead of function itself and even called function via () => {  } but same result.

`<button type="button" onClick={ this.onSubmitForm }>Save</button>`

```
onSubmitForm = (e) => {
    // e.preventDefault();

    const response = axios.post('http://localhost/util/index.php/api/record', {name: 'test'} );
    console.log(response) // Even this line is logged once in console ;

}
```

Comment: We're going to need more code. What's the component that `onSubmitForm` prop is on?

Comment: One is the click event, another is submit event, remove click event from button, attach onSubmit handler to the form

Comment: @Rikin I did, same result

Comment: If browser dev tools says one api request and console.log prints only once too, why would you think it's a frontend problem. Something is wrong with your api, check your backend code. Also try making requests to the api using some other method like the command line or postman to verify where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither your react app nor the API, it is the browser itself. Have a look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

> A preflight request to let the server know what HTTP method will be used when the actual request is made.

Answer (score 0):

If in the Google Dev tools shows only 1 xhr call. Then it's not a front-end problem. It might be something wrong with the api function in server side. Maybe it calls the insert query twice.

Comment: API is working perfectly when I call it via curl and Advanced REST client in Google chrome